# bundler and ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, date, bundler

Why am I not able to use these lines in a Gemfile:

```
gem 'date'
gem 'pp'
```

Must these be required in file instead like this:

```
require 'date'
require 'pp'
```

Or is there a way to mix them into your Gemfile so they are available project wide?

I think that date and pp are part of ruby 1.9.2 core and as a result are different from regular gems but I don't exactly understand why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because those are not Gems but part of the Ruby standard library. But the standard library isnt loaded by default, hence the `require` statements

Comment: Is there a way to say "load the whole standard library by default" on the ruby level?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Its a ton of overhead.